# Application Cache Error event: Manifest fetch failed (404)

Tags: html, application-cache

I have already one site, for that I have created one mobile site using jquery mobile with application cache features. (Both have same urls)

Using apache2 userAgent settings I redirected to mobile site for (Android and Iphone).

When It redirected to mobile site, I get below error:

Application Cache Error event: Manifest fetch failed (404)

### test.manifest

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# version 1
CACHE
/index.html
/static/js/main.js
/static/css/style.css
```

Example:

**main site:**
www.example.com/

**mobile site**
www.example.com/

www.example.com/test.manifest open directly but using redirection it give 404 error randomly.

Please suggest any solution.

Answer (score 1):

One thing wrong with your manifest. You need a colon after CACHE.

Answer (score 0):

Is your redirect using code something like this?

$.mobile.changePage

I see similar issues if I use bookmarks to some of my pages rather than $.mobile.changePage.

Answer (score 0):

404 is standard for the page not existing. My guess is your link is incorrect or you might have forgotten to upload your manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your paths should start without / that's often the case for me, even if the first element is a folder. But you've probably already checked that.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was able to make it working like

```
CACHE MANIFEST
#v1.0.1
NETWORK:
*
```

I had the 404 error when it was like:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
#v1.0.1
NETWORK
*
```

so without : in the NETWORK section.